# email img tracking script downloading the file instead of displaying it

Tags: php

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private',false);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="blank.png"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize('1x1img.png'));
readfile('1x1img.png');
exit();
```

The script above, force downloads the file, instead of showing it as an image.

What is it missing so it won't download the file?

Comment: `Content-Disposition: attachment`.

Comment: You could just remove the header entirely.

Comment: Where would I set the file name?

Comment: Why do you need to set the filename? It'll default to whatever the script name is. A browser should still embed it, even if the extension is `.php`.

Comment: Although `inline` will also work

Comment: So its not the same name as the original file, hence can't be looked up.